# gitignore ending star behavior

Tags: git, gitignore, git-extensions

The following is a default .gitignore setting (when established via GitExtensions):

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.
**/packages/*
# except build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
!**/packages/build/
```

It confuses me because I understand from [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) that ** can span directories, but * cannot. And therefore I don't expect ignore of the following path

```
my/packages/build/foo
```

to match `**/packages/*`. And therefore the inversion line `!**/packages/build/` that follows seems to be unnecessary.

Yet it feels like someone added the inversion for a reason.

Is there undocumented behavior for a single asterisk at the end of a file spec that will also cause ignore of subdirectories, or is the default .gitignore incorrect?

Comment: Apparently (the documentation doesn't say this), adding a wildcard to a file-only pattern like `foo`, for example `foo*`, turns it into a pattern that matches a file or directory. Also * at the end is effectively ** because of the nature of file system iteration.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't expect […] the following path
>
> ```
>    my/packages/build/foo
> ```
>
> to match `**/packages/*`.

And it doesn't.  But you can summarily ignore entire directories, and `**/packages/*` *does* match `my/packages/build`.  Ignored directories aren't inspected at all, so the consequence is exactly as if your ignore pattern was `**/packages/**` except Git can more easily detect that it doesn't have to look in `packages` subdirectories.  Git has changed recently to make the subtle distinction between `**/dirname` and `**/dirname/*` behavior less consequential, but the holdovers still show up in `.gitignore`s written by people who learned the old-school way.

Comment: Pattern `packages` matches file packages but not directory packages/. Great. Pattern `packages/*` matches files AND directories within packages/. Hmm - ok accepted. Now what does `*.obj` do? I assumed it was only to match files ending with obj extension. Does it also match directories?

Comment: `packages/` would match only a directory, but a bare name matches anything with that name -- so `*.obj` would match directory names ending `.obj` too.